# ResponseBuilder gives 200 OK HTTP response even for server error

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, httpresponse

I am using javax.ws.rs.core.Response api to build and send back response to front end from my spring boot backend. I have a controller as follows.

```
@GetMapping(value = "/details")
public Response getDetails() throws ServiceException {
    try {
        //logic to get details
        return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(details).build();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage());
        return Response.status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).entity(e.getMessage).build();
    }

}
```

But I am getting 200 OK as the response status for the HTTP Request in the browser/postman even in the case of exceptions. Because of this, the ajax success block executes instead of the error block when there is an exception. Is there any way to make the error block execute in this case? I don't want to throw an exception as it sends the entire stack trace in the response.

Comment: What exception does your server throw? are you catching the same exception?

Comment: Yes, same one. There is no issue is catching the exception and building the Response object with the error message. The is a status field in the response body and that is set to 500. But the HTTP status of the response is 200 OK.

Answer (score 1):

`@GetMapping` is from spring mvc and spring-mvc is not JAX-RS compliant. So don't mix to use them together. Either use pure spring-mvc or pure JAX-RS . you can try to return a spring-mvc `ResponseEntity` (equivalent to JAX-RS `Response`) instead:

```java
@GetMapping(value = "/details")
public ResponseEntity getDetails() throws ServiceException {
    try {
        //logic to get details
        return ResponseEntity.ok(details);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage());
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(e.getMessage);
    }

}
```

Comment: glad to hear ~~